# Python 3: list of 2 elements into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Python3
OMG, sorry for a probably often repeated question in one way or another. For me, manipulating lists has always been like a black box of headaches, and I've been battling for an hour now with no results.

I have a list in the form:

```py
[('John', 'first@email.com'), ('John', 'second@email.com'), ('Jack', 'third@email.com')]
```

I would like to transform this into an iterable dictionary (that I could then bulk insert as a document using pymongo) so that it looks like this:

```py
 new_posts = [{"sender": "John",
               "email": "first@email.com"},
              {"sender": "John",
               "email": "second@email.com"},
              {"sender": "Jack",
               "email": "third@email.com"}]
```

How would this be achievable in an easy to read and efficient manner?

Comment: What have you tried? And if you think it's an oft-repeated question, did you look up any of the previous questions? What did you get from them?

Comment: @skytreader, while I appreciate your effort to promote introspection and learning, rest assured I wouldn't ask for help if I really weren't having a hard time with it. We are all mindful of other people's time here I believe (just look at my posting time, when I ask for help at 2am it means I just wasn't able to get that done sooner in order to go to bed... )

On the same token, I feel it would have been better if you had taken the same time, to point me in the right direction rather than to just patronize me like that (given that you provided no answer to the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
>>> a = [('John', 'first@email.com'), ('John', 'second@email.com'), ('Jack', 'third@email.com')]
>>> [dict([('sender', x[0]), ('email',x[1])]) for x in a]
[{'sender': 'John', 'email': 'first@email.com'}, {'sender': 'John', 'email': 'second@email.com'}, {'sender': 'Jack', 'email': 'third@email.com'}]
```

This will convert list to dict

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [('John', 'first@email.com'), ('John', 'second@email.com'), ('Jack', 'third@email.com')]
new_posts = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    new_post = {}
    new_post["sender"] = data[i][0]
    new_post["email"] = data[i][1]
    new_posts.append(new_post)
```

Another way of solving it..

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list = [('John', 'first@email.com'), ('John', 'second@email.com'), ('Jack', 'third@email.com')]
your_result = [{'sender': sender, 'email': email} for sender, email in your_list]
```